# How to Remove search and export buttons if no data available in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

> I want to remove the "Search" and "Export (copy,excel,csv,pdf...etc)
>   Buttons" if data is not available in the datatable.

I can able to find out the length of the datatable is "0" but unable to find any solution how to remove the buttons and search control.

Currently datatable is showing "No data Available" which is required for me. I can able to show the dattable properly.

This is what i have tried so far.

```
var table = $('#tblParametersPopUp').dataTable(
{
    dom: 'Bfrt',
    bPaginate: false,
    oLanguage: {
        sSearch: '<i class="fa fa-search">&nbsp; </i>'
    },
    buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'copy',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>',
                    titleAttr: 'Copy'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'excel',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>',
                    titleAttr: 'Excel'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'csv',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>',
                    titleAttr: 'CSV'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdf',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>',
                    titleAttr: 'PDF'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i>',
                    titleAttr: 'Print'
                }
    ]
    //,
    ////initialization params as usual
    //fnInitComplete: function () {
    //    if ($(this).find('tbody tr').length <= 1) {
    //        $(this).parent().hide();
    //    }
    //}
});
if(table.fnSettings().aoData.length == "0")
{
    //alert('no data');
    //I want to remove the default search and export buttons here.
}
```

Please Help!

Comment: maybe try ?  $('i').hide();

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether table is empty or not and if empty destroy table and initialize datatable with search disable

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var table =$('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]
    } );
if ( ! table.data().count() ) {
    $('#example').dataTable().fnDestroy();
        $('#example').DataTable( {
        searching: false
    })
}
} );
```

Comment: You mean to say destroy the table and recreate again without search and buttons? Any other easy solution ?

Comment: Like this way only I update datatable with new data from ajax response.

Comment: Downvoter please add comments or even better add your answer, I will delete and upvote yours answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use `drawCallback`

```
drawCallback: function (settings) {
                $this.datatable.button(0).enable(settings.json.recordsTotal > 0);
                $this.datatable.button(1).enable(settings.json.recordsTotal > 0);
                $this.datatable.button(2).enable(settings.json.recordsTotal > 0);
            }
```